# disassembly of C#: why is DUMPBIN native code so different from Debug's Disassembly?

Tags: .net, disassembly, native-code

Suppose this is my program simpleCsharp.exe:

```
namespace simpleCsharp
{
    public class Program
    {       
         public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
                uint x = 0xFEFEFE;
                uint y = 0xEEEEEE;
                uint z;
                uint[] list = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8 };
                uint[] array = { 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD };
                z = x + y + list[2] + array[1];
                z = z - (y << 1);
                return 0;           
        }
    }
}
```

If I view the disassembly of a simple C# program in Debug's Disassembly window, the [native code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) output at least makes some sense. For example, here is the Debug's disassembly of Main, with Optimization on:

```
uint x = 0xFEFEFE;
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  sub         esp,28h 
00000006  xor         eax,eax 
00000008  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax 
0000000b  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax 
0000000e  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000011  cmp         dword ptr ds:[037D14ACh],0 
00000018  je          0000001F 
0000001a  call        763B370F 
0000001f  xor         edx,edx 
00000021  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx 
00000024  xor         edx,edx 
00000026  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],edx 
00000029  xor         edx,edx 
0000002b  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],edx 
0000002e  xor         edx,edx 
00000030  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx 
00000033  xor         edx,edx 
00000035  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],edx 
00000038  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],0FEFEFEh 
uint y = 0xEEEEEE;
0000003f  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],0EEEEEEh 
uint z;
uint[] list = { 0, 1, 2, 4, 8 };
00000046  mov         edx,5 
0000004b  mov         ecx,79882916h 
00000050  call        FD95FD70 
00000055  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax 
00000058  lea         ecx,[ebp-14h] 
0000005b  mov         edx,37D25E0h 
00000060  call        761A4716 
00000065  lea         eax,[ebp-14h] 
00000068  push        dword ptr [eax] 
0000006a  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-24h] 
0000006d  call        761A47F3 
00000072  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-24h] 
00000075  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax 
uint[] array = { 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD };
00000078  mov         edx,4 
0000007d  mov         ecx,79882916h 
00000082  call        FD95FD70 
00000087  mov         dword ptr [ebp-28h],eax 
0000008a  lea         ecx,[ebp-18h] 
0000008d  mov         edx,37D25ECh 
00000092  call        761A4716 
00000097  lea         eax,[ebp-18h] 
0000009a  push        dword ptr [eax] 
0000009c  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-28h] 
0000009f  call        761A47F3 
000000a4  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-28h] 
000000a7  mov         dword ptr [ebp-20h],eax 
z = x + y + list[2] + array[1];
000000aa  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
000000ad  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
000000b0  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-1Ch] 
000000b3  cmp         dword ptr [edx+4],2 
000000b7  ja          000000BE 
000000b9  call        763B6900 
000000be  add         eax,dword ptr [edx+10h] 
000000c1  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-20h] 
000000c4  cmp         dword ptr [edx+4],1 
000000c8  ja          000000CF 
000000ca  call        763B6900 
000000cf  add         eax,dword ptr [edx+0Ch] 
000000d2  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 
z = z - (y << 1);
000000d5  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
000000d8  add         eax,eax 
000000da  sub         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax 
return 0;           
000000dd  xor         eax,eax 
000000df  mov         esp,ebp 
000000e1  pop         ebp 
000000e2  ret
```

However, if I run DUMPBIN on the same C# assembly (with Debug Info = "None" so it doesn't just show bytes), i.e.

```
dumpbin "simpleCsharp.exe" /disasm /out:"simpleCsharp_dump.txt"
```

the native code output in the generated file doesn't even closely resemble what I viewed in Debug's Disassembly. I don't see even a single instruction or value from the Debug's Disassembly in the file from dumpbin. So the 2 lines of native code (above) are nowhere to be found. This is the case whether I run dumpbin on the assembly generated from Visual Studio (2010) or I use **[ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)** to generate a native image, and run dumpbin on the native image file simpleCsharp.ni.exe.

Optimization is **on** in Debug, and build is set to Release, the only difference between the assembly I run Debug on, and the assembly I give to ngen, is Debug Info = "None".

```
dumpbin simpleCsharp.ni.exe /disasm
```

Here is the disassembly of the simpleCsharp program when I run dumpbin on the native image file:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B9u9yFU99BOcYjNmNGRmNTItZjQ0NC00YmI0LWEyZTQtNjdkNDdhYTc2MmNm&hl=en

I would at least expect to see the number FEFEFE or EEEEEE show up in the output of dumpbin somewhere, and it does show up in Debug Disassembly.

Could someone please explain why I don't see *one* line of Debug's disassembly code in the dumpbin output from the native image file, for the same program? If it's because of optimization, would you mind giving a little detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are forgetting about the just-in-time compiler.  An assembly doesn't contain machine code, it is generated at runtime by the jitter from the IL in the assembly.  You can look at the IL in the assembly with tools like ildasm.exe or Reflector.  Dumpbin.exe has poor support, it can dump the CLR header, that's about it.

Beware that the ngen-ed image contains machine code that was optimized by the jitter.  That optimizer alters the machine code a great deal.  Optimization is off by default in the debugger.  To see it, you have to debug the Release build and change a debugger option.  Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" option.  Also beware that the generated code can be just plain different in places because it was precompiled instead of jitted.  The jitter can do a better job because it has knowledge that isn't available up front.

Comment: But I mentioned using ngen.exe, says MSDN:
"native images, which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code, and installs them into the native image cache on the local computer. The runtime can use native images from the cache instead of using the just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile the original assembly."

Comment: Hans/NoBugz, I just updated the question. I have optimization turned on in Debug, yet this code is more than 'plain different in places', it's nothing alike. If you wouldn't mind having another look, please...

Comment: That's what you get when you disassemble data instead of code.  Note the large number of 00.  And the bytes that start with 6x or 7x, they are strings.  Not sure what you are looking at, clearly it isn't the machine code.  Looks like IL and metadata to me.